# How to run a local aurora node?

Tags: blockchain, evm, aurora-evm

- I want to sync data from local node.
- local node need to support eth_rpc as "https://mainnet.aurora.dev" did.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can run a full node of NEAR plus Aurora RPC alongside it. The latter one is here: https://github.com/aurora-is-NEAR/aurora-relayer.

However, the best way to run a full node can be found at https://github.com/aurora-is-near/partner-relayer-deploy. It is installed and deployed by a single command. The database is restored from the dump. It's the combo of NEAR Core and Aurora relayer, which increases the efficiency of the node.

Comment: How about running a testnet or localnet node ?

Answer (score -1):

The repo https://github.com/aurora-is-NEAR/aurora-relayer and https://github.com/aurora-is-near/partner-relayer-deploy are deprecated. Please follow https://github.com/aurora-is-near/standalone-rpc if you want to run a standalone RPC.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33105105)